# Flutter: No version of NDK matched

Tags: flutter, android-ndk, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 20.0.5594570. Versions available locally: 21.4.7075529
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i deleted the 21.4.7075529 file in the ndk folder so it will get the compatible ndk version for this project